# How can I fabricate this data in SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am confused on how I can get this table from a query

```
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+-------+
|Product Name |Today    |WTD       | MTD     |YTD    |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+-------+
|Name1        |78       |80        |89       |89     |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+-------+
|Name2        |56       |78        |88       |78     |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+-------+
```

where the values are averages, 'Today' is average value for today, 'WTD' means week to date average value, 'MTD' means month to date average value and 'YTD' means year to date average values.

Honestly, I don't know SQL very well, also I am using SQLALchemy(which I don't know much also).
The table I want to get the data from are:

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(80))

class ProductAssessment(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product_assessment"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'), nullable=False)
    product_name = relationship(Product, backref=backref('assessments'),
                   cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")
    score = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    record_date = Column(Datetime, default=func.now())
```

For now what I have been able to get is average value for the product by doing this:

```
result = DBSession.query(Product.name.label("Product name"), func.avg(Product_Assessment.score).label("YTD")).filter(Product.id==Product_Assessment.product_id).group_by(Product.name)
```

Please I will appreciate it much if someone could help me on this

### Edit

Sample data:
Product

```
+-------+--------+
|id     |name    |
+-------+--------+
|1      |Name1   |
+-------+--------+
|2      |Name2   |
+-------+--------+
```

Product_Assessment

```
+----------+---------+--------+----------+
|product_id|id       |score   |Date      |
+----------+---------+--------+----------+
|1         |1        |80.16   |2015/1/5  |
+----------+---------+--------+----------+
|2         |2        |85.19   |2015/1/18 |
+----------+---------+--------+----------+
|1         |3        |81.70   |2015/1/18 |
+----------+---------+--------+----------+
|1         |4        |70.11   |2015/1/18 |
+----------+---------+--------+----------+
```

Expected output:

```
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+
|Product name|Today   |WTD    |MTD    |YTD   |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+
|Name1       |70.11   |70.11  |77.32  |77.32 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+
|Name2       |85.19   |85.19  |85.19  |85.19 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+------+
```

That's the data @mandeep_m19

Comment: post a sample dataset and the sample output that you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the previous answer, I would rather use an `INNER JOIN`. I do agree with the `CASE WHEN` construction, but since the number of rows to consider is different for each value we need to compute the average ourselves (`AVG` won't work). It is a rather heavy construction but I don't see anything simpler.

```sql
SELECT 
   P.name
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN PA.record_date = <todays date> THEN PA.score ELSE 0 END) 
   / SUM(CASE WHEN PA.record_date = <todays date> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS today
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN PA.record_date BETWEEN <start date> AND <end date> THEN PA.score ELSE 0 END) 
   / SUM(CASE WHEN PA.record_date BETWEEN <start date> AND <end date> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wtd
   ,SUM(CASE when PA.record_date BETWEEN <start date> AND <end date> THEN PA.score ELSE 0 END)
   / SUM(CASE WHEN PA.record_date BETWEEN <start date> AND <end date> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mtd
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN PA.record_date BETWEEN <start date> AND <end date> THEN PA.score ELSE 0 END)
   / SUM(CASE WHEN PA.record_date BETWEEN <start date> AND <end date> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ytd
FROM product P
INNER JOIN product_assessment PA
ON (P.id = PA.product_id)
GROUP BY P.name;
```

Comment: Can you do this same thing in subquery?

Comment: You can use a subquery to compute the sums but it won't affect performance. Why do you want a subquery? If it is about simplifying the code, you can define a function right before too.

Answer (score 1):

In plain SQL you can achieve the same like this (specify the dates yourself accordingly):

```
select product.name
, avg(case when product_assessment.record_date = <todays date> then product_assessment.score else 0 end) as today
, avg(case when product_assessment.record_date between <start date> and <end date> then product_assessment.score else 0 end) as wtd
, avg(case when product_assessment.record_date between <start date> and <end date> then product_assessment.score else 0 end) as mtd
, avg(case when product_assessment.record_date between <start date> and <end date> then product_assessment.score else 0 end) as ytd
from product, product_assessment
where product.id = product_assessment.product_id
group by product.name;
```